# Send Keystrokes to Windows App From Web App

Tags: asp.net, windows, winapi, web-applications

I have a bit of an odd requirement that involves integrating with a legacy windows application via a browser-based application.

What needs to happen is pretty simple, but I'm not sure it's technically possible.  The browser application will need to locate the windows application by its window name, then send a series of keystrokes to it.

I have no control over the windows application (it's third party), so can make no modifications to it.

Forcing the user to use a specific browser is not desirable, but is acceptable if there is no other way.

A macro approach would also be acceptable, but some data would have to come from the web app (maybe via the clipboard)?

Comment: Is the legacy application running on the same machine as the web browser or the same machine as the web server?

Comment: The app runs on the same machine as the web browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Been a while since I've looked at this sort of thing, but IE's [Browser Helper Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_Helper_Object) is probably your best bet. Adobe's in-browser PDF reader, Flash, etc. are BHOs.

Comment: I think Flash might be an ActiveX control rather than a BHO specifically; but that's mostly splitting hairs :) The key thing is that you'd need to build some sort of Win32 plugin that can break out of the browser sandbox - and you'd better be really really sure that some other malicious web page can't somehow use it to do its bidding instead. For example, a malicious page might decide to locate the CMD window and send the string "echo y | format c:" or similar.

Comment: Firefox of course has a similar mechanism.  I'm not sure about Chrome.